# Changing the string value of another class

Tags: java

Currently, I am running into a problem which I don't know how to change another class's string value.

There is this button, after I clicked it, I want it to change the another class's string value which is declared in that class.

In the main class, I have already created the object:

```
public class BTRSMain {
    private MainMenuPage mainmenupage;
public void start() throws Exception{
    mainmenupage = new MainMenuPage();
}}
```

The following code shows the button function:

```
public class OriginSubmit implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent SignUpSubmit){
        if(mainmenupage.OriginCB.getSelectedItem().equals("APU")){
            //After clicking the button the string will change into:
            //String[] Destination = ("Seremban","Melaka","Ipoh","Kuantan");
        }
    }
}
```

The another class name is "MainMenuPage.java".
The declaration of the string and inclusion of the string in a combo box:

```
public class MainMenuPage {
    String[] Destination;
    JComboBox DestinationCB = new JComboBox(Destination);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with the concept of setters and getters.

Comment: Yeah this seems like a very basic question that would be learnt about when learning the basics. How much of the basics of programming in Java do you know?

Comment: It's a bad idea to declare `throws Exception`. Throw a specific checked exception if any.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can do this. You can do it by creating an object of MainMenuPage class in OriginSubmit class.

```
public class OriginSubmit implements ActionListener {
MainMenuPage mainMenu = new MainMenuPage(); //this line of code to be added

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent SignUpSubmit){
    if(mainmenupage.OriginCB.getSelectedItem().equals("APU")){
        mainMenu.Destination = new String[]{"Seremban","Melaka","Ipoh","Kuantan"}; //line of code to be added

        //After clicking the button the string will change into:
        //String[] Destination = new String[]{"Seremban","Melaka","Ipoh","Kuantan"};
    }
}
}
```

I'll explain the second method now .If you don't want an object, you have to make the MainMenuPage class static. Then use it in the OriginSubmit class.

```
public static class MainMenuPage { //make it static
String[] Destination;
JComboBox DestinationCB = new JComboBox(Destination);
}

public class OriginSubmit implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent SignUpSubmit){
    if(mainmenupage.OriginCB.getSelectedItem().equals("APU")){
        MainMenuPage.Destination = new String[]{"Seremban","Melaka","Ipoh","Kuantan"}; //this line of code to be added

        //After clicking the button the string will change into:
        //String[] Destination = ("Seremban","Melaka","Ipoh","Kuantan");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When I change to static, it says modifier static not allowed here.

Comment: then just create an object of that class and you can change the Destination variable.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to java, so I don't really understand, can you show me?

Comment: See the above code now. Sorry I made a mistake earlier. Now edited it. Try this.

Comment: Two lines of code should be added. I've mentioned that in the comments.

Comment: Actually I have created the object of the MainMenuPage, I have edited my codes, you can have a look, and it still cannot work. Thx

Comment: mainMenu.Destination = new String[]{"Seremban","Melaka","Ipoh","Kuantan"};  You haven't added this line.Take a look at my answer. The first code in my answer.

Comment: array dimension missing, String cannot be converted to String[].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the classes MainMenuPage and  OriginSubmit are in the same package, replace your commented code with the following:

```
/*Construct the MainMenuPage object */
MainMenuPage mainMenuPage = new MainMenuPage();

/*Invoke the required method on the constructed object*/
mainMenuPage.Destination = new String[]{"Seremban","Melaka","Ipoh","Kuantan"};
```

However if your classes are in separate packages, the `package-private` members (such as 'Destination') from one class cannot be directly accessed in another. You will have to add a public `setter` method in the class to allow the outsiders to invoke it. E.g. `public void setDestination(String[] newDestination){this.Destination = newDestination;}`

Comment: array dimension missing, String cannot be converted to String[].

Comment: You need to show your full code of both the classes. The error your have quoted here means you are trying to assign a plain String object to a String array.

Answer (score 0):

Keep **ENCAPSULATION**! And try to follow clean code (variables naming).

And learn basics of OOP and Java. Because this is reached by using getters and setters and they are basics.

```
public class MainMenuPage {
    private String[] destination;
    JComboBox destinationCB = new JComboBox(destination);

    public MainMenupage() {
        this.destination = new String[4];
    }

    // Your other code

    public void setDestination(String[] destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public String[] getDestination() {
        return this.destination;
    }
}
```

Then just call this setter:

```
public class OriginSubmit implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent SignUpSubmit){
        if(mainmenupage.OriginCB.getSelectedItem().equals("APU")){
            // I dont know where are you declare object for MainMenu class
            mainMenu.setDestination(/* your value */);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows this error, actual and formal argument lists differ in length.

Comment: I think that you have to add your own constructor for your class. I dont know how you wrote it now, but I think problem is you missed constructor. Please, try to review Java basics.

Comment: @KennKelentrixion Have they not shown you the basics yet as a student before giving you an assignment? I can't imagine they would have asked you to do that without talking you through it first. Also assignment and homework questions shouldn't be asked on here.

Comment: @Popeye True.. +1 for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

The subject you're searching for is called Multilevel inheritance. With the keyword "extend" the classes are no longer separated, they are forming a virtual super-class which consists of all methods and variables systemwide. Multilevel inheritance is a powerfull tool for rapid application programming.

```
public class BTRSMain {
    private MainMenuPage mainmenupage;
public void start() throws Exception{
    mainmenupage = new MainMenuPage();
}}
public class OriginSubmit implements ActionListener extends BTRSMain {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent SignUpSubmit){
        if(mainmenupage.OriginCB.getSelectedItem().equals("APU")){
            //After clicking the button the string will change into:
            //String[] Destination = ("Seremban","Melaka","Ipoh","Kuantan");
        }
    }
}
public class MainMenuPage extends OriginSubmit {
    String[] Destination;
    JComboBox DestinationCB = new JComboBox(Destination);
}
```